# How to have the pop-up window for method definition in intelliJ while selecting the methods available?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, netbeans

I am moving to intelliJ and trying to have the useful method-definition window that i used to have in netbeans.

In netbeans, and while seeking the methods available, you always have a small pop up window that gives you the definition of that method in javadoc.

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOjVJ.jpg)

I know, you can press ctr+shift+I for Quick Definition, but it only shows an example but not the definition. and i also know that ctrl+b will open the whole java doc and take you to that method but it looks not practical.

I also know the feature of hovering over the method, but, once again, i am seeking for the pop-up window you have WHILE selecting the method.

is there any way possible to have the old good pop-up window?

thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> (by default) to bring QuickDoc.

Comment: is there any way maybe to have automatically opened while having the methods list?

Comment: As far as I know, you can only have the window appear when you move your mouse over an item in code (press CTRL+SHIFT+A to bring an option search window, search for "show quick documentation on mouse move") option.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the Keymap tab in Preferences you can search for "Quick Documentation" and see the available shortcuts. I'm using the macOS keybindings but it's similar on Windows or other platforms. It shows me three shortcuts: `F1`, `Ctrl+J` and `Ctrl+Mouse Button 2`.

When you are selecting through the autocomplete popup, press `F1` or `Ctrl+J`, then a documentation popup will show up alongside it. So you can see the docs while cycling through the methods list. It's not automatic but it's the closest thing you can get as of now.